# IIS7 .NET (2.0, 4.0) completely hosed with a Bad Request (Error Code 400) error

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

All of a sudden all of my websites on my server return 400 Bad Request Error.  I don't have a clue what happened.  App Pools are running in Classic pipeline mode (4.0, 2.0), doesn't matter.

Every URL that I type comes back as 400 Bad Request.  Real URLs, even fake URLs that don't exist (which should come back as 404) all are 400.

```
http://mywebsite.com/AFile.aspx
http://mywebsite.com/AFolder/AnotherFile.aspx
http://mywebsite.com/Bfolder/YetAnotherSillyPage.aspx
http://mywebsite.com/A_stupid_URL_that_does_not_even_exist_fjfjffjfj.aspx
```

Everything 400 Bad Request. Totally screwed up my ASP.NET. Where should I begin to look?  Machine.config? Web.config?

**UPDATE:**
After trying a million different settings, I finally set the App Pool to Integrated and set the Identity to LocalSystem and all of a sudden it works.

Comment: Does this happen when you browse your page from iis?

Comment: Can you see the detailed error on the EventViewer ? The general error that you see now have no details, but in the EventViewer you can see the real error and the details.

Comment: Where do I look for "detailed" errors?  I'm looking in Event Viewer/Custom Views/Web Server and I don't see any red errors, only informational.  Where else should I look?

Comment: Somebody mentioned that IIS7, by default, comes "locked down".  Could it be that .aspx pages need to be "turned on".  If so, where do I check if it's "turned on"?

Answer (score 1):

Bad Request usually is HTTP.sys stopping the request due to something really bad (like invalid URLs, or something like that).
You probably should look at HTTP.sys logs (Not IIS) at:
**C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR**

Also, maybe something got broken in the http.sys configuration so try running:
**netsh http show servicestate**

And see if for your web site it has the correct bindings, for example it could be that the bindings are only listening on only specific IP Addresses and yet its coming from another one, or similar problem but with Host Name, etc.

Finally you might want to run:
**C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd list sites**

And see if the bindings and status makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried some mixture of re-installing (or uninstall/install) asp.net using the aspnet_regiis.exe utility? That's fixed strange IIS/ASP.NET server issues for me in the past.

Have you looked in the event log for any error messages or further clues?

Comment: No error level events in the Logs, only informational (and non-relevant) events.  I have not tried aspnet_regiis.exe, I was hoping to avoid reinstalling, if possible.